# Ros2 service String providing unexpected Result �2���

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am using :
kernel Linux 5.8.0-50generic(x86_64)
Distribution Ubuntu 20.04.2LTS
ROS2-Foxy
C++ std 14
I am trying to create a service
In which i passing two string and expected to get a concatinated string but i am gettin g unexpected results.
Here are the output texts

SERVICE OUTPUT:-

```
[INFO] [1620193993.198502097] [rclcpp]: Ready to add two string.
[WARN] [1620193993.278931507] [rclcpp]: this is what i am receiving 123
[INFO] [1620193993.279032788] [rclcpp]: Incoming request
a: �.��� b: �2���
[INFO] [1620193993.279054157] [rclcpp]: sending back response: [�2���]
[WARN] [1620195212.142007473] [rclcpp]: this is what i am receiving 123
[INFO] [1620195212.142103931] [rclcpp]: Incoming request
a: �.��� b: �2���
[INFO] [1620195212.142131196] [rclcpp]: sending back response: [�2���]
```

CLIENT SIDE TEXT:-

```
(FIRST ATTEMP)
[INFO] [1620195212.073202455] [rclcpp]: this is what we are sending @mG��
[INFO] [1620195212.142851611] [rclcpp]: Result: @mG��

(SECOND ATTEMPT)
[INFO] [1620193990.932057565] [rclcpp]: service not available, waiting again...
[INFO] [1620193991.932632967] [rclcpp]: service not available, waiting again...
[INFO] [1620193992.933087641] [rclcpp]: service not available, waiting again...
[INFO] [1620193993.279721272] [rclcpp]: Result: ��H;�
```

I am attaching github  link for source code:-
https://github.com/aniketkalra11/rcl_srvcli.git

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/377709/ros2-service-string-providing-unexpected-result--%EF%BF%BD2%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD%EF%BF%BD/) by [anni](https://answers.ros.org/users/74114/anni/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-05-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When printing an `std::string` (using the `%s` specifier), you need to actually print the underlying C string and not the `std::string` object. Otherwise you will get "garbage" like that. This is a very common error with the [`printf` functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf) (and `RCLCPP_INFO` does pretty much the same thing underneath). For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7769715/c-and-printf-strange-character-output

You can do this by calling the `c_str()` method of the `std::string` object. I actually just tested and you should be getting a compiler warning if you don't do that. If you did get warnings when compiling, don't ignore them!

In your case, this would look like:

```
RCLCPP_INFO(rclcpp::get_logger("rclcpp"), "sending back response: [%s]", response.get()->concatinated_aa_bb.c_str());
```

Same thing for the other times you use `RCLCPP_INFO` with `std::string` objects. Just add `.c_str()` after all `std::string` variables to print them.

---

Originally posted by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) with karma: 641 on 2021-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5